# How to convert all type of images to text using python tesseract

Tags: python-tesseract

I'm trying to convert all type of images in a folder to text using python tesseract. Below is the that I'm using, with this only .png files are being converted to .txt, and other types are not being converted to text.

```
import os
import pytesseract
import cv2
import re
import glob
import concurrent.futures
import time


def ocr(img_path):
    out_dir = "Output//"
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img,lang='eng',config='--psm 6')
    out_file = re.sub(".png",".txt",img_path.split("\\")[-1])
    out_path = out_dir + out_file
    fd = open(out_path,"w")
    fd.write("%s" %text)
    return out_file

os.environ['OMP_THREAD_LIMIT'] = '1'
def main():
    path = input("Enter the path : ")
    if os.path.isdir(path) == 1:
        out_dir = "ocr_results//"
        if not os.path.exists(out_dir):
            os.makedirs(out_dir)

        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
            image_list = glob.glob(path+"\\*.*")
            for img_path,out_file in zip(image_list,executor.map(ocr,image_list)):
                print(img_path.split("\\")[-1],',',out_file,', processed')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    main()
    end = time.time()
    print(end-start)
```

How to convert all type of image files to text. Please help me with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the `ocr` function.

First of all, the following does convert all type of image files to text.

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img,lang='eng',config='--psm 6'))
```

However, what the next chunk of code does are

1. Select those file with `.png` extension using a regex
2. Create a new path with the same filename and a a `.txt` extension
3. Write the OCR output to the newly create text file.

   ```
   out_file = re.sub(".png",".txt",img_path.split("\\")[-1])
   out_path = out_dir + out_file
   fd = open(out_path,"w")
   fd.write("%s" %text)
   ```

In other words, all types of images files are converted but not all are written  back correctly. The regex matching logic only replace `.png` with `.txt` and assign to `out_path`. When there is no `.png` (other image types), the variable gets the same value as the original filename (e.g. `sampe.jpg`). The next lines of code open the original image and overwrite with the OCR result.

One way to fix is by adding all the image formats you want to cover into the regex.

For example,

```
out_file = re.sub(".png|.jpg|.bmp|.tiff",".txt",img_path.split("\\")[-1])
```